# StringTemplate to generate Cobol layout

Tags: cobol, stringtemplate

I am tasked with writing some Java to read data from a DB2 table and write into a file in a fixed with format that can be input to a Cobol program.
The Cobol layout looks like so

```
01 PERSON
   10 FIRST-NAME PIC X(10)   (i.e 10 bytes fixed width)
   10 LAST-NAME  PIC X(20)   (i.e 20 bytes fixed width)
   10 MIDDLE-INITIAL PIC X(1)
```

In Java the fields are available to me as Strings.  Using the docs I came up with something like this

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleInitial;

    Person(String inFirstName, String inLastName, String inMiddleInitial){
        this.firstName = inFirstName;
        this.lastName = inLastName;
        this.middleInitial = inMiddleInitial;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getMiddleInitial() {
        return middleInitial;
    }

}
```

and then in main, I had these lines of code

```
    st = new ST("$p.firstName$ $p.lastName$ $p.middleInitial$", '$', '$');
    st.add("p", new Person("Ethelred", "TheUnready", "X"));
    System.out.println(st.render());
```

Executing produces this result

```
Ethelred TheUnready X
```

What should I do to ensure the output looks like so

```
Ethelred  TheUnready         X
```

while a name like John Q Smith would like so

```
John      Smith              Q
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
spaces = "                                                         "
outLine =   (firstName + spaces).substring(0,10)
          + (lastName + spaces).substring(0,20) 
          +  middleInitial;
```

There are a number of packages for writing Fixed width files from java (have a search of Sourceforge).

There are even a few packages that can use a Cobol Copybook to read/write the file:

- [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/)
- [cobol2j](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cobol2j/)
- legstar

These packages are an overkill in this case but are useful if the copybook is more complicated.

---

disclaimer I wrote JRecord.

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward.  So you're saying there is no need to muck around with StringTemplate.

Comment: There is no need to use the StringTempate